# Getting the key value of parent in JSON in Handlebars

Tags: json, node.js, parsing, key, handlebars.js

I have a JSON called hierarchy whose contents load dynamically. So i don't know the contents while parsing. The structure is something like this.

```
a: {
   b: {
      c 
      }
   }
```

Now i have to parse and get the key value c.
This is what i am doing

```
{{#each hierarchy}}
            <li>{{@key}}
                <ul>
                    {{#each ../@key }} (This is where i am confused)
                        <li> {{@key}}
                            <ul>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    {{/each}}
                </ul>
            </li>
        {{/each}}
```

Now i don't know how to refer to the key value of b in the next loop.
Can anyone help me out in this?

Comment: Please correct your `json` format...

Comment: @VikrantKashyap Let's suppose this is the format of the data that i have. Consider this a javascript object. How to get the value then?

Comment: @VikrantKashyap I am able to parse till the second level. But i need the key in the third loop. That is what i am unable to access.

Comment: Please define the actual format of json keys and structure... This doesn't explain anything

Comment: { us: { east: { g: {}, n: {}, b: {}, n: {}, g: {} } },
     europe: { east: { i: {}, i: {} } },
     taiwan: { east: { t: {}, t: {}, t: {} } },
     singapore: { east: { s: {}, s: {} } } } }